# Isolate this variable in a trigonometric equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need to isolate $y$. I've been trying to change the $\tan$ for the $\cos$ but at the end I don't know how to continue.

$$x = \tan(3y)+\frac{1}{\cos(3y)}$$

Thanks

Comment: $x =\tan 3y + \sec 3y$. Hence $\dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{\tan 3y + \sec 3y} = \sec 3y - \tan 3y$. Subtracting we get $\dfrac{1}{2} \left(x-\dfrac{1}{x} \right) = 2 \tan 3y.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making use of the identity $$ \tan^2 a + 1 = \sec^2 a $$

You can reorder the terms like this

$$ x - \tan 3y = \sec 3y $$

Squaring both sides

$$ x^2 - 2x\tan 3y + \tan^2 3y = \tan^2 3y + 1 $$
$$ x^2 - 2x\tan 3y = 1 $$
$$ \tan 3y = \frac{x^2-1}{2x} $$

**Edit:** Here's another way, using the [tangent half-angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula).

Let $t = \tan(3y/2)$ then
$$ x = \frac{2t}{1-t^2} + \frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2} = \frac{(1+t)^2}{1-t^2} $$
$$ x = \frac{1+t}{1-t} $$

Solving for $t$ by cross-multiplying we get 
$$ t = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$x=\dfrac{\sin3y+1}{\cos3y}=\dfrac{1+\tan\dfrac{3y}2}{1-\tan\dfrac{3y}2}=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4+\dfrac{3y}2\right)$$

using [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution)

Comment: I checked your answer by substituting y for 50, and the last step is wrong. I'm already stuck in the step before (which is right), and I also came to this pretty ugly equation: $x = \frac{1+tan(3y/2)²+2tan(3y/2)}{1-tan(3y/2)²}$